# Is my router/network compromised?

Tags: router, honeypot

I have a ZTE (F670L) router for my home network. Since past few days, I have been observing SSL certificate error (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID), occurring abruptly more frequently than before. This initially started happening with Firefox (version 112.0.2), and all the websites that wouldn't open with Firefox, would open just fine with chrome (version 112.0.5615). But a few days later, this started happening with chrome as well as with edge browser! Now this happens for websites across the spectrum range (academics, marketing, sports, news etc.), barring a few ones such as, say, Wikipedia or [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) maybe. Also, this happens on all of my devices such as laptops, tablets and mobiles and with Windows as well as Ubuntu.

Interesting thing is, if and when I switch to a different network at that time, (say a data network on my mobile or a WiFi via a hotspot from my mobile data), all the websites seem to open correctly. Another important thing I have noticed is that, usually when there is an SSL certificate error, there is an option of an "advanced" button, which takes the user to the website at "their own risk"!. But if I try to force my way to any website in the context of my present issue, a lot of random pages start opening (e.g. I usually land at some random betting or other advertisement webpages!), instead of the required one. Also, if I try the open the website from the google search result page several times (usually say after trying more than 9-10 times, going back and again clicking the website link), the correct website is served to me (with all the security certificate with correct validity!). Last important point is that very old normal html pages (non-HTTPS) are also not available to me now!

Few months ago, I tried to expose my router for attacks (port 22 and 23) for a honeypot on one of my machines (typical Cowrie implementation, using one of my virtual machines as honeypot and another virtual machine as the proxy back end ... nothing fancy!). This has started happening after a long time (maybe 3 months) since my honeypot experiment.  I am attaching two screenshots of the certificate error against one of the famous news websites in my country (India). I have not found any extra IP address in my router. The router firmware seems proprietary, and is managed by TR 069 protocol. Interestingly, among the IP addresses from across the globe that attacked my honeypot, I found a few IP addresses from the same ISP whose services I am availing!I wanted to know if there is a sure way to figure out if the problem pertains to my router possibly being compromised, or is it something else? I hope I have supplied all the required information!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at your DNS settings. Probably your devices get an IP address via DHCP along with DNS settings from your router. This could be a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Someone is definitely hijacking your connections and inserting all these betting popups and advertisements.

TLS is doing its job and telling you your connection is compromised (yay for TLS). Don't visit any websites where you're logged in (this includes Google if you're logged into Google) as the attacker could hijack your login session.

It could be your router. I agree with the suspicion of your router. A lot of home routers do have security problems and this does seem like the sort of thing an attacker could do with a home router. Alternatively, it could be a router at your ISP, but it's less likely.

It *probably* doesn't have anything to do with your honeypot project - although if attackers could escape from the honeypot then it's a possibility that the honeypot was used to attack the router from the inside.

I bet if you replace your home router with a new one, your connection will be back to normal. Perhaps your ISP will send you a new one if you tell them what is happening. I am not sure how to *prevent* it from happening other than buying a different router without security bugs - but it's impossible to know if a router has security bugs until it gets hacked.

One way it could be your fault is if the router has a very easy-to-guess password. Some routers can be configured from the Internet if you know the password, and that would make it *very* easy for an attacker. If an attacker can escape from the honeypot, they can access the router's configuration page from your network, too.